# Minimum value of $ab+bc+ca$

Tags: inequality, contest-math, maxima-minima

Given that $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R^+}$ and $(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)=1$

> Find the Minimum value of $ab+bc+ca$

My try: Letting $x=a+b, y=b+c, z=c+a$ we get

$$a=\frac{x+z-y}{2}, b=\frac{x+y-z}{2},c=\frac{y+z-x}{2}$$
$$xyz=1$$

Now the problem is to minimize $$ab+bc+ca=\frac{xy+yz+zx}{2}-\frac{x^2+y^2+z^2}{4}$$

Now by $A.M-G.M$ we have
$$\frac{xy+yz+zx}{2}\geq \frac{3}{2}\times \sqrt[3]{x^2y^2z^2}=\frac{3}{2}$$

But I am stuck for $\frac{-(x^2+y^2+z^2)}{4}$

Comment: FYI, using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24(a%2Bb)(b%2Bc)(c%2Ba)%3D1%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24ab%2Bbc%2Bca%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Aminimum&p=1), there's [How to show that $ab+bc+ca\le \frac34$](/q/3198470) which shows what the maximum value of your expression can be.

Comment: @John Omielan, but that's not what OP asked here.

Comment: @Ennar I'm aware of that, which is what I prefixed my statement with "FYI", and I didn't vote to close as a duplicate. Nonetheless, I perhaps should have been more explicit in my comment that what I found was essentially the "opposite" of what the OP was asking about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This doesn't have a well-defined minimum. Solve
$$(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)=1$$
for $c$ to get
$$
c=\frac12\left(-(a+b)\pm\sqrt{(a+b)^2-4\left(ab-{1\over a+b}\right)}\right)
$$
Let $a=b=1/N$ where $N$ is some
"big enough" number, then $a+b\approx0$ and $c\approx\sqrt N$ and $ab+bc+ca\approx {1/\sqrt N}\approx 0$, up to factors of two. Obviously, it never reaches the minimum though, since $a,b,c>0$, so we don't have a well-defined minimum value.

Comment: But the answer is $\frac{3}{4}$ at $a=b=c=0.5$

Comment: @Umeshshankar Sorry I don't get your point.

Comment: But the answer given in the book is, the minimum value of $ab+bc+ca$ as $\frac{3}{4}$

Comment: @Umeshshankar Note that, as I stated in my [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4476385/minimum-value-of-abbcca#comment9384606_4476385) linking to [How to show that $ab+bc+ca\le \frac34$](/q/3198470), the value of $\frac{3}{4}$ is actually the *maximum*, i.e., it's not the minimum. Perhaps your book has a typo, and it meant to ask for the maximum instead of the minimum?

Comment: Ok I got it now Thank u

Answer (score 1):

With this separation you can't find a minimum ; since $x^2+y^2+z^2$ is not bounded. Just take the sequence $(x_n,y_n,z_n)=(n,n,1/n^2)$, $n\in\mathbb{N}^\ast$, so that $x_ny_nz_n=1$, then $x_n^2+y_n^2+z_n^2=2n^2+1/n^4$ is not upper bounded. You may maximize the 'whole' function $x^2+y^2+z^2-2(xy+yz+zx)$ by Lagrange multiplier (for example).
[Lagrange multiplier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier)

Answer (score 1):

To find a potential boundary value, why not try $a=0$? - Then you are minimising $bc$ subject to $bc(b+c)=1$ and this is rather easier to work with.

This may give you an idea - now to prove it, given you can't have $a=0$ but can get as close as you wish.

Eliminating one of the variables in this way is one way of trying to understand what is going on when you have three variables like this. Sometimes the same idea can be used to reduce many variables to a special case with two - it can indicate, for example, whether you need to separate the values as much as possible or make the variables as close to each other as you can. And that can pint you in the direction of the right kind of technique (I always find it easy to mix up max/min $\gt/ \lt$ in this kind of question unless I'm very careful).